# Pandas performance varies between mac and linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pandas, jenkins

I have a simple function.

The dataframe has `1713078` rows.The following simple function:

```
self.df = self.df[~self.df['RR'].str.contains(":c", na=False)]
self.df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

takes `2x` time on centos6.4 via jenkins with 16 gb ram and 16 CPU's , when compared to mac 16 gb ram etc.I am not sure what can be the culprit here.
Can it be due to `jenkins`?as rest all is same.I am not even sure what more details can i give here.

Comment: Can you run the same code directly from the shell and not through jenkins?

Comment: Not really, unless the user that runs jenkins has some limits (cpu usage/memory/etc), and I think it will be hard to find the cause without a having the code run directly from the shell.

Comment: Check here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/08/nice-renice-command-examples/ it might give you some more information.

Comment: Another question - you sure that you run the exact same python version on both servers? python2.7.X? 32bit/64bit? Same pandas version?

Comment: what's the memory usage of the df in df.info() ?

Comment: So, no jenkins on your local mac but scheduling through jenkins on the linux machine? How do you time it... does it account for job queue and start time? About how long is the run... if we are talking a few seconds then its just overhead. How busy is that server? If its also running other jobs like a big compile, it will be slow. How do processor speeds compare?

Comment: @tdelaney jenkins on linux vs driect run on mac.....timed through datetime.datetime.now()......its in minutes....1.5 minutes vs 3 minutes....processor is 16 cpu's 2 ghz each..........on linux....`ntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X7550  @ 2.00GHz`.........on mac...8 cpu i7 2.2ghz  is it due to processors? as ram is same for bth